# CiviCRM Navigation Menu is not displayed

Tags: menu

After some time working with CiviCRM, the **Navigation Menu** is not displaying.
I've been researching different solutions, but neither of them seem to be the issue.

Could someone guide me what I should be looking at or give me some tips to lead me to the cause of the problem?

I'm working with **CiviCRM 5.32.1**, **mySQL 5.7.27** and **php 7.3.14** on **Drupal 7.69**.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a number of causes including perhaps gremlins

- Permissions on the directories used by the asset builder plug in
- The URL (including either http or https) in the civicrm.settings file
- Cache in both Drupal and Civi
- Reset directories in Civi